# is there a firefox addon equivalent to chrome's html5 outliner?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

[this addon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/afoibpobokebhgfnknfndkgemglggomo) is awesome, and I just love it, and would like to find its equivalent for firefox, as firefox is awesome, and I just love it :)

it basically provides a nice outline of  elements to navigate the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a small firefox addon to provide this functionality. There are some minor issues with it, but it's already quite usable.

You can find it here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/table-of-contents/

Answer (score 3):

Seems like there is a [bookmarkelt](http://code.google.com/p/h5o/) available:

> The current (Nov, 2009) HTML5 draft defines quite a precise algorithm,
>   for producing an outline for HTML documents. h5o is an implementation
>   of the algorithm in JavaScript.
>
> The goals of this project are:
>
> - A bookmarklet, to produce outlines in decent browsers
> - A Firebug extension, to help HTML5 development
> - A repository of HTML5 outlining test cases

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this addon:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/html5_outliner/

This is better than the one mentioned above!!

Comment: Can't click on heading to jump to it. Also failed for some pages.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a few and found HeadingsMap to be the best. It also lets you click on the heading to jump to it.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/headingsmap/

Comment: It would be nice, if there would be an open source addon similar to the one you mentioned.